# How to center an element in div

Tags: html, css

I have a character A center within a box. I want to move A to the center of this box.

```
    <div class = 'flex-container'>
        <div class = 'box1'> A </div>
    </div>
```

```
.flex-container{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    font: Tahoma;
    align-items: center;
}

.flex-container > div{
    font-size: 40px;
}

.box1{
    background-color: grey;
    margin: 5px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

I can wrap A with the tag p then change the margin of this tag to set the position of A. But then one has to calculate how to set the margin size. Is there any more straightforward way to achieve this goal?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can add flex display for `.box1` container

```css
.flex-container{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    font: Tahoma;
    align-items: center;
}

.flex-container > div{
    font-size: 40px;
}

.box1{
    background-color: grey;
    margin: 5px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
    <div class = 'flex-container'>
        <div class = 'box1'> A </div>
    </div>
```